# How are the following functions O(N^3)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm taking the "Intro To Algorithms" course on Coursera, and I've arrived at the video which deals with Big-Theta, Big-Omega and Big-O notation.  The end-of-video quiz presents the following question:

```
Q: Which of the following functions is O(N^3)?

a) 11N + 15lgN + 100
b) (N^2)/3
c) 25,000*(N^3)
d) All of the above
```

I answered "c" and was told my answer was incorrect, and that the correct answer is actually "d".  The explanation provided by the course wasn't much help:

```
Recall that big-Oh notation provides only an upper bound on the growth
rate of a function as N gets large. In this course, we primarily use 
tilde notation because it more accurately describes the function—it 
provides both an upper and lower bound on the function as well as the 
coefficient of the leading term.
```

I was under the impression that one should drop the lesser-order terms (i.e. "15lgN + 100") and focus only on the highest-order terms.  Furthermore, I can't see how N^3 could be the upper bound on a quadratic (as opposed to a cubic) function like N^2.

So my question is, why are "a" and "b" classified as O(N^3) in this case?

Comment: Use the definition of big-O instead of heuristics and impressions.

Comment: @Anonymous: what does that mean?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: I guess @Anonymous is talking the same thing. Use the book definition, but not the impression/thought which we have for Big-O notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know, `f(n) = O(g(n))` implies `f(n) <= constant* g(n)`, right?
In other words, it means, when you plot the graph of `f(n)` and `g(n)` then after some value of, `g(n)` will always be more than `f(n)`.

Here `g(n)` is `N^3` and remaining comes in `f(n)`. Now, `N^3` is always `>=` options `a`, `b`, `c`. hence answer id `D` :)

**Edit:**
Following statements are true,

- n=O(n)
- n=O(n^2)
- n=O(n^3)

But only `n = O(n)` is tight upper bound and that is what we should use in time complexity derivation of algorithms. If we are using 2nd and 3rd option, then we are misusing the Big-O notation or let's say they are upper bounds but not tightly bounded!

**Edit 2**: See following image
[image]

`G(x)` is tight upper bound for `F(x)` and `H(x)` is upper of `F(x)` but not tight! Still we would say, `F(x)=O(G(x))` & `F(x)=O(H(x))`. When somebody in exam/interview ask for time complexity they are asking for tight bounds, but not an upper bound. Unfortunately, tight upper bound and upper bound terms are used in exams/interviews interchangeably.

Comment: My understanding of big-O notation is that it specifies the "worst-case scenario" of how many operations will be performed with a given algorithm.  In other words, for a given problem size N, the algorithm will never need to perform more operations than the result of plugging the aforementioned N into the big-O expression.

So if N=1000, why would it take 1000^3 operations to calculate a problem of (1000^2)/3 difficulty?

Comment: Also, based on your answer, I would infer that any expression greater than f(n) is a correct big-O expression.  So if I rephrase the question from O(N^3) to O(N^4) (i.e. "Which of the following functions is O(N^4)?"), then "a", "b" and "c" are all still less than this new big-O value I've set.  But there can only be one "worst-case scenario" for how many operations an algorithm will need to perform, and the change I've made to the question doesn't change the "worst-case scenarios" for "a", "b" and "c".  Can you see why I'm confused?

Comment: Yup. If you change question to O(N^4), still the answer holds :). The problem here is, we are not bounding the functions tightly! Tighly bounding means, least upper bound. Edited answer for better understanding :)

Comment: @toomanyrichies It's not about the *worst scenario*, it's about a *pessimistic approximation*. We often can find and calculate in detail the worst case, but sometimes we can only approximate it (for example Shell-sort) in which case we use an upper bound, which possibly is never reached but defines some kind of guarantee. Then it's not 'you need N^3 steps in the worst case' but rather 'you'll never need more than N^3 steps, even in the worst case'.

Comment: @Abhishek that was the cause of my confusion.  I assumed the question was asking which of the equations has a tight upper bound of O(N^3), when apparently that was not the question's intent.

Comment: @toomanyrichies Yup. Coursera doesn't go with the human notations. It goes by definition/theory. It clearly implies, Coursera  was right and you understood Big-O properly. It is us who uses/thinks the notations in wrong way. :)

Comment: I wouldn't say that n=O(n^2) is "misusing notation." It's good to keep in mind the formal definition, which you should use when taking the course, writing a paper for a CS journal, or talking to mathematicians, and keep this separate from the common incorrect usage, used by most programmers, that O(f) means something like c1*f+c2, or perhaps theta(f). When you hear someone say O(n^2), you can try to figure out which definition is meant based on the context, speaker, and speaker's intended audience.

Answer (score 4):

The explanation says it: "Recall that big-Oh notation provides only an upper bound on the growth
rate of a function as N gets large."

In this particular context, the upper bound can be read as "does not grow faster than N³".

It is true that `11N + 15lgN + 100` does not grow faster than `N³`.

Answer (score 3):

Think of O(N^2) also being O(n^3), O(n^4) and so on. O(N^2) is always bound under O(n^3), therefore O(n^2) is indeed O(n^3).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#/media/File:Big-O-notation.png

Comment: So you're saying that N^3 may not be the most accurate upper bound for equations "a" and "b", but it's ONE POSSIBLE upper bound (albeit one that will never be reached by 2 of the 3 equations).  Is that right?

Comment: @RichieThomas I know this is late but yea pretty much

Answer (score 3):

As many have already quoted a function f(n) which has upper bound say O(n) complexity is also O(n^2) , O(n^3), O(n^4)... etc

Does that make sense or if it gets confused, think in absolute layman terms.

Suppose an process takes max upper bound of 10 secs to execute, come whatever be the input we can conclude this :-

- Whatever be the input the execution will complete in less or equal to 10 seconds.

If that is true, even the following is true :-

- Whatever be the input the execution will complete in less or equal to 100 seconds.
- Whatever be the input the execution will complete in less or equal to 1000 seconds.

and so on.......

And thus you can correlate the answer. Hope that gave you a glimpse.